# Open file and read Double data

Tags: java

Trying to read double data from the file that has different contents. For example if it is a double then the message should be  "Double number is 23.5". and if it is not double number the message should be "Sixty three is not a double number". The file contents are

97.9

100.1

Three

Sixty three

77

12.4

3002.4

76

Cool

34.6

This is it

............

The code i wrote opens the file and scans next line But does not seem to properly work.

```
class ReadDouble 
 {

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


try

{

    File textFile = new File ("doubleData.txt");
    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner (textFile);
    String str = scan.nextLine();

    while(scanFile.hasNextLine())
    {

        double num = Double.parseDouble(str);
        if(str == num)
        {
            System.out.println("Double number is" + str);
        }

    }//end while


}//end try

catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{
   System.out.println(str + "Is not a Double number");
}
```

}

}//end class

Comment: `scan.nextLine()` should be inside your while loop, otherwise you don't ever get past the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should call `String str = scan.nextLine();` within the loop otherwise you only ever read the first line. Also, your `try / catch` block should be wrapped around `double num = Double.parseDouble(str);` within the `while` loop otherwise you will not make another call to `scan.nextLine()` after you encounter your first non-double.

Finally, you shouldn't do `if(str == num)` as this will always be false. If `Double.parseDouble(str)` does not throw an exception, it contains the double found on that line.

Here is a solution that reads from standard in:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadDouble {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String str = scan.nextLine();

        try {
            num = Double.parseDouble(str);
            System.out.println("Double number is " + num);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println(str + " is not a Double number");
        }       
    }
}
}
```

Another option is to use `Scanner` to see if the next element is a `double` if it is read it  using `nextDouble()` otherwise read using `nextLine()`.

Comment: It works only when you enter something but it does not read the whole file though. Would the wile(scan.nextLine) loop inside try catch will give me all the contents in the File?

Comment: This example only works when you enter something because the input to my `Scanner` is `System.in`. You need to change the input to be the file you wish to read.

Comment: Got it completely forgot the file 0))

Answer (score 2):

your try-catch should be inside the while loop, else it will come out in the first exception and rest of the lines will be ignored.

Comment: Makes sense because it gives the user another chance to enter correct info.

Answer (score 0):

Given your file format, I would not bother with Scanner. Just read each line, pass it to Double.valueOf(String) and catch the exception if it is not a double.